# What's the tag "obscure-terms" for? Is it necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have the tag [obscure-terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obscure-terms). It has 36 questions and the only thing obscure about them is the thought process that lead people to tag them with this tag. Mostly words that seemed obscure to the OPs, sometimes regarding the actual word obscure, sometimes completely arbitrary.

I don't think there is a proper tag this tag can be made synonym of. I think we should start with gradually re-tagging the questions manually.

What should we do with the tag?

Following the [guideline from Meta.SE on burninating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) I answer the following questions:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   Hell no! The questions are an arbitrary bunch only kept together by tag.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   If there were a discernible concept, maybe. The tag has no information and googling and meta dictionaries like onelook.com cannot provide any information about *obscure terms* being an established concept of any sort.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   It certainly does not seem so. There are also no followers of the tag. The tag is completely arbitrarily used.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Certainly not. They range from concerning the words *obscure* to regarding more or less uncommon words.

So let's get it ...

[image]

Comment: Burninate it. *whistles for Trogdor*